# Rubyn on Rails 6: Adding database support to an existing Rest API Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rest

I'm working with Ruby on Rails in the creation process of an RestAPI, I create the application using this command:

```
rails _6.1.5_ new myproject --api
```

Now I need to add database support to the project, specifically I need to use PostgreSQL, so far I found this parameter but for new projects:

```
rails _6.1.5_ new myproject --api --database=postgresql
```

My question is: is there a way (parameter, command?) to add postgresql support to my existing project?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change from sqlite to postgresql is simple, just add `gem 'pg'` to Gemfile, then bundle install and after that change the default section of your `database.yml` to:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
```